# How to check whether LiveStream (Audio Only) is up on Wowza or not?

Tags: android, live-streaming, wowza, vitamio

I am streaming from **Wowza to Mobile (Android)**. I am using **Vitamio** streaming library. The actual flow is like, Wowza don't have live stream up, when my app hits the Wowza, but after a while Wowza gets live stream up. Now I again want to hit the Wowza to check whether live stream up or not.

All I want is, my app should hit the Wowza in every 5 sec to check the stream up or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to query your Wowza server to see if your stream is active or not. If so, then you can use a Wowza REST API command to query Incoming Streams (you need at least version 4.2+).

For example, to query application "live" for all Incoming Streams, you can send the following command via HTTP:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/live/instances/_definst_
```

You would get a response similar to:

```
{"serverName":"_defaultServer_","incomingStreams":[{"sourceIp":"<hidden>","isPTZEnabled":false,"applicationInstance":"_definst_","name":"wowzademo.stream","isRecordingSet":false,"isStreamManagerStream":true,"isPublishedToVOD":false,"isConnected":true,"ptzPollingInterval":2000}],"outgoingStreams":[],"recorders":[],"streamGroups":[],"name":"_definst_"}
```

Which shows that I have an Incoming Stream called "wowzademo.stream" (among other things). You can also change your response to be xml instead of json, if you prefer.

### Update

In response to your comment, I would add:

1. make sure that you are on at least version 4.2+; I would actually recommend using version 4.3 since there were some REST API fixes on the latest version;
2. If you are on version 4.3, then test with disabling authentication by setting `<AuthenticationMethod>` and `<DocumentationServerAuthenticationMethod>` to none under the Root/Server/RESTInterface container of the conf/Server.xml file;
3. Make sure that you add the restUserHTTPHeaders property to have the value "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*|Access-Control-Allow-Methods:‌​OPTIONS,GET,PUT,DELE‌​TE,POST|Access-Contr‌​ol-Allow-Headers:Con‌​tent-Type".

If the above still does not work for you, try enabling the debug properties by setting `<DiagnosticURLEnable>` to true, and adding `<debugEnable>` (set to true/Boolean type) property in the RESTInterface container. You can view the logs generated by checking the access logs in the logs/ directory.